# Equivalent of Is.factor and is.numeric in RCPP

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to port some R code for a distance function to RCPP:

```
distanceFunction <- function(row1, row2){
  distance = 0
    for(f in names(row2))
      if (is.factor(row2[[f]])){
        if (!(row2[[f]] == row1[[f]]))
          distance = distance + 1
      } else if(is.numeric(row2[[f]])) {
        distance = distance + abs(row2[[f]] - row1[[f]])
      }
  distance
}
```

Unfortunately I couldn't find how to check for the datatype (factor or numeric in RCPP)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Factor" is not a type at `SEXP` level representation and is hence not something Rcpp supports at the C++ level. I suggest you call your function with the integer representation.

The equivalent of `is.numeric()` can be tested in a number of ways; see [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) for how it is done in C, and several posts at [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) for C++ ways. You can use traits as well as `is*` predicates.